# Save a website, open the saved .htm file in browser, edit its css/html, view live changes

Tags: web-development, css, html-editor, live-preview

I'm learning webdesign and I want to do what you can do in chrome and firefox web developr tools, but make it all save in my system and persist changes, and edit in my choice of editor.

So, like I save this page by hitting ctrl+s, save it in a folder as `something.htm`, open the htm in browser and its css/etc files in sublime text, make changes there and see them in the browser.

Is there anything that can make me able to do that?

Comment: Does the page in the browser has to change *while* you type in Sublime Text, or is it sufficient to reload it after you save the file?

Comment: [Related (closed) question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12823873/1591669) on [so].

Comment: You [can enable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts#Source_editor) Sublime Text key bindings (as well as Vim or Emacs) in Firefox Developer Tools' source editor.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/). Cross Platform - Windows (XP+), Linux, Max OSX, via javascript also iOS & Android. You'll probably want one of the [Browser Extensions](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/87979-how-do-i-choose-the-best-integration-method-) for ease of use.

There is also a [Sublime plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LiveReload) for it but I haven't tried that out. I *believe* that will let you preview as you type rather than only on save.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) Works well in grabbing the content of a website completely.It grabs all the files needed to make the website and stores it locally for offline browsing. Works in Windows,Linux,Mac OSX.

Another alternative is to use [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).It comes for Windows,Linux.For MacOSX it is better to use [Brew](http://brew.sh/).

You can use the command **wget -r --no-parent http://site.com** to grab the website.

Now for making changes to the offline webpages you can use addons like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for firefox and chrome has inbuilt [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) similar to firefox. So you can make changes and can see the changes in live.

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to use the Sublime Text editor for changing the code, and have the changes displayed in the browser without having to reload the page manually.